# How do I move data from one class to another?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Sorry if it is something really simple I am new to this.
I am trying to add 2 array lists and one String from the first class(office) to the second class(LineChart_AWT) however, when I run it I get null values in the second array. How would I change that?
here is the code, it gets data from a database, and it does it correctly, as when I use `System.out.print()` in this class it  prints the list, but when I do it in the other class it prints null.

```
public class Office<selectTime, conn, DB_URL, USER> extends Container {
    private ArrayList<Integer> levelList;
    private ArrayList<Date> theTimeList;
public Office(JFrame f, Object worker) throws SQLException {
addDataButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String gettingTime = "SELECT Time AS theTime FROM Measurement WHERE Site_ID = (SELECT Site_ID FROM Site WHERE Site_Name = '"+locationSelector.getSelectedItem()+"') ORDER BY Time ASC LIMIT 0,1000000";
                System.out.println(gettingTime);
                ResultSet selectTime = null;
                theTimeList = new ArrayList<Date>();
                try {
                    selectTime = finalStmt.executeQuery(gettingTime);
                    while(selectTime.next() == true) {
                        String theTime = selectTime.getString("theTime");
                        System.out.println(theTime);
                        Date timeValue = null;
                        try {
                            timeValue = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(theTime);
                            theTimeList.add(timeValue);
                        } catch (ParseException parseException) {
                            errorBox.setText("There was and error");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                    errorBox.setText("There was and error");
                }

String gettingLevels = "SELECT Level AS theLevel FROM Measurement WHERE Site_ID = (SELECT Site_ID FROM Site WHERE Site_Name = '"+locationSelector.getSelectedItem()+"') ORDER BY Time ASC LIMIT 0,1000000";
                System.out.println(gettingLevels);
                int theLevel = 0;
                try {
                    ResultSet selectLevel = finalStmt.executeQuery(gettingLevels);
                    while(selectLevel.next() == true){
                        int SL = selectLevel.getInt("theLevel");
                        theLevel = SL;
                        levelList.add(theLevel);
                    }
                } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                    errorBox.setText("There was an error");
                }
                LineChart_AWT chartPanel = new LineChart_AWT(

                        "Tank Level Against Time" ,
                        "Tank Level Against Time");
                String curLocation = String.valueOf(locationSelector.getSelectedItem());
                chartPanel.location = curLocation;
               chartPanel.dates = theTimeList;
                chartPanel.levels = levelList;
                chartPanel.pack( );
                RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen( chartPanel );
                chartPanel.setVisible( true );
}
        });
}
}
```

```
public class LineChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame
{
    ArrayList<Integer> levels;
    ArrayList<Date> dates;
    String location;public LineChart_AWT(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) {
        super(applicationTitle);
        JFreeChart lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                chartTitle,
                "Time", "Tank Level",
                createDataset(),
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true, true, false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(lineChart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(560, 367));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
        System.out.println(location);
        System.out.println(dates);
        System.out.println(levels);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not using a ctor and setting these fields directly is a super bad idea.  The values you set are obviously `null` at the start, so the problem is in `Office`, in some code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: the code is correct until this point, the lists are done properly as when i printed them they print actual lists, ill add the values to the code rn

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] that demonstrates what the problem is, so we can actually see it?  It's obviously in the code driving these classes, we need to see that code.